# Error: Forbidden You don't have permission to access /kibu5/< on this server

Tags: php, apache, permissions

I have my PHP code for my project, but when try to load in the localhost as 
`localhost/kibu5` it gives an error:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /kibu5/< on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.37 (Win64) PHP/7.2.14 Server at localhost Port 80

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is a hosting/permissions problem, not a programming one. You'll need to ensure your server is set up correctly.

Comment: Kindly Guide in achieving so, am new into this

Comment: You probably need to add `Require all granted` to the virtual host config